# Not updating the state instantly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

So, when I click on the add to cart button on the Screen2, it logs articleToCart aka cartArticle as empty array... Only when I go back to Screen1 and than again on the Screen2, pressing add to cart button again it logs cartArticle array with one item even though add to cart button was clicked 2x... How can I make it that when I click on add to cart button, it updates the state immediately? What am I doing wrong? I am using react navigation v2. Is it possible to setState trough params and that to be instant not like this, with delay?

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
  state = {
    articles: {
      article: [],
    },
  cartArticle: []
};

articleToCart = () => {
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    cartArticle:  prevState.cartArticle.concat(prevState.articles.article)
    };
  });
};


qrCodeOnReadHandler = ({ data }) => {
fetch(data)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => [
    console.log(json),
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      articles: {
        ...this.state.articles,
        article: json[0],
      }
    }),
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
      addToCartOnPress: () => this.articleToCart(),
      articleToCart: this.state.cartArticle,
    })
  ])
  .catch(err => {
    alert("Nesto ne valja. Pokusajte ponovo!");
    console.log(err);
  });
 };

render() {
  return (

    );
  }
}
```

Second screen

```
class Screen2 extends Component {

addToCartHandler = () => {
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const articleToCart =navigation.getParam("articleToCart","Nedostupno");
    const add = navigation.getParam("addToCartOnPress", "Nedostupno");

console.log(articleToCart);

add();

};

goBackHandler = () => {
   this.props.navigation.goBack();
  };

 render() {
   return (
        <View style={styles.buttons}>
          <CustomButton color="#1DA1F2" onPress={this.goBackHandler}>
            Back
          </CustomButton>

          <CustomButton color="#1DA1F2" onPress={this.addToCartHandler}>
            Add to Cart
          </CustomButton>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **qrCodeOnReadHandler** on screen1:

```
[
    console.log(json),
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      articles: {
        ...this.state.articles,
        article: json[0],
      }
    }),
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
      addToCartOnPress: () => this.articleToCart(),
      articleToCart: this.state.cartArticle,
    })
  ]
```

you are returning an array with your functions as its indices.
try changing it to this instead.

```
{
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      articles: {
        ...this.state.articles,
        article: json[0],
      }
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
      addToCartOnPress: () => this.articleToCart(),
      articleToCart: this.state.cartArticle,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`setState` is async, you can't read values just after setting them** .. but you can use `setState` callback, sth. like this:

```
.then(json => {
  console.log(json)
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    articles: {
      ...this.state.articles,
      article: json[0],
    }
  }, () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
      addToCartOnPress: () => this.articleToCart(),
      articleToCart: this.state.cartArticle,
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: EDIT: actually it does exactly what it did before, it navigates to Screen2 but id does not update state, again I need to go back to Screen1 and than to Screen2 so I can see changes...

Comment: If I do something like this articleToCart.push(article) that I also send trough params in addToCartHandler on the Screen2, I immediately  get that article in array as soon as I click add to cart button. No need to go back and than again... How can I get the same effect but not mutating state like this?

Comment: ah, I finally understand the real problem/intention ;)  In `normal` react states aren't preserved on routing, both screens would be recreated on transitions. In this case it's sth wrong in passing (back) modified data or rerendering of first screen when is hidden...hmmm.... 'Normal' solution is lift state up into parent of both components (in web usually state is saved into localStorage to carry values between pages).

Comment: When I think about it, state is actually updated on Screen1 but my problem is that I am on Screen2 and I do not know how to rerender it...

Comment: Use [redux](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/managing-state-in-a-react-navigation-app-with-redux-6d0b680fb595) or [app state](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1552) (link to solution at bottom)